# Need help adding OpenLayers to Geonode

Tags: openlayers-2, geonode

I just installed [GeoNode](http://geonode.org/) and really love the manner in which it helps me arrange the contents related to the map but I am not sure about adding OpenLayers to it.

Well here is where I am faltering,

1. I am not sure where the OpenLayers code goes? I felt that I could use the code to customize GeoNode's look and feel and make use of the customization features on the Web Page, but to publish the Map you receive a embed link which only gives you the Map and not the other features.
2. If we have to use OpenLayers separately, like in the HTML, I am not sure, How to run that static html file, since the localhost is being used by the GeoNode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am not sure where the OpenLayers code goes? I felt that I could use
>   the code to customize GeoNode's look and feel and make use of the
>   customization features on the Web Page, but to publish the Map you
>   receive a embed link which only gives you the Map and not the other
>   features.

You could get GeoNode's source and customize the map viewers. The source code can be found at [Github](https://github.com/GeoNode/geonode).

> If we have to use OpenLayers separately, like in the HTML, I am not
>   sure, How to run that static html file, since the localhost is being
>   used by the GeoNode.

GeoNode has a Geoserver component. You could make your own OpenLayers-based viewer and just add the layers from GeoNode's Geoserver component.

It can be rather hard to customize GeoNode though. The codebase is huge. Should you want to get started with client development first, you might want to check the [OpenGeo client SDK](http://suite.opengeo.org/docs/usermanual/tutorials/clientsdkintro/index.html). It has the components they used to build GeoExplorer, GeoEditor and even the GeoNode map viewer, I believe.

Comment: Hi @R.K. thanks for the reply. I was able to do that, but honestly being a newbie, I don't think Geonode is a place to create your own customizable tools. There were lot of issues and I am presently developing my application using simple GeoExt (which is also not that easy but allows development of customizable tools better)

Comment: I was just giving you an idea on how to do it. You did ask. But yeah, it is more of a prepackaged solution. You might also want to check out the opengeo client sdk.

Comment: I was not complaining dude. Geonode is indeed amazing and definitely the way future for OpenGeo Tech but it's just that it's new and the developers are focused more on the Software development than documentation for now. Yup I have tried opengeo sdk too but I feel GeoExt is the best bet for now.

Comment: I'm glad you discovered GeoExt but you asked about Geonode. Therefore, you'll get answers about Geonode. This isn't about you complaining. This is about you changing the question midstream. If you changed your mind, please create another question or at least update your old question. It's annoying.   Answers take time. Be more considerate.